# Mustache: Serializer for class 'MustacheContent' is not found

Tags: kotlin, serialization, mustache, ktor

I'm trying to do a project using Ktor and Mustache (amongst other things). However, when I tried templating with Mustache, following [this tutorial](https://ktor.io/docs/mustache.html#configure), I get the following error:

```
500: kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'MustacheContent' is not found.
Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly.
```

Of course,  I can't change the MustacheContent class for it to be Serializable, since it's part of the Mustache package. Any idea as to what might fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-5337). The fix will be delivered in the Ktor 2.3.0 release. As a workaround, you can place an installation of the `ContentNegotiation` plugin after an installation of the `Mustache` plugin.